# Passing the value of an id with @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**The goal**: to pass an userId and two timestamps to the controller via an `@Ajax.ActionLink()`.
So far what I have:

```
<table class="table table-hover ALStable thickborder" id="resultsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Access level</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count(); i++)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Ajax.ActionLink(Model.Users[i].Username, "UserTracking", new { userId = Model.Users[i].Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "userTracking" }, new { @style = "font-weight:bold;" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Users[i].AccessDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%" } })</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3 class="text-primary shadowedtext">Time filter</h3>
<p>Show from:</p>
<div id="datetimepicker1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      inline: true,
      format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
      defaultDate: moment().subtract(1, "days")
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
      setDate(e.date.valueOf(), 0);
    });
  });
</script>

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FromDate)

<p>Show until:</p>
<div id="datetimepicker2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      inline: true,
      format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
      defaultDate: moment()
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
      setDate(e.date.valueOf(), 1);
    });
  });
</script>

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UntilDate)

<div id="userTracking"></div>
```

Controller method

```
public ActionResult UserTracking(int userId, long from, long until)
{
  Models.GPSInformation detail = new Models.GPSInformation();
  .....
  return PartialView(detail);
}
```

Also there are two date time pickers on the page, where the user can select the date interval. For testing I've filled the from and until parameters with dummy data. 
 That part is solved where the id is populated with the selected date's timestamp, but I can't pass those two values when the actionlink is clicked. 
Any ideas, help is really appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a form with `FormMethod.GET`, not a link

Comment: So there is no other way to solve it just with form?

Comment: Not unless you want to write scripts to get the values and update the href attribute of the link - but why would you not want to use a form?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, but this page displays many user name in a table and all the names are the link to a partial view with the results of the search. Btw if I can update the href value that is fine.

Comment: Then stop using the obsolete `Ajax.ActionLink()` methods an use jquery and ajax.

Comment: That would be really nice to if you can help me out with that.

Comment: Then show a bit more code including the view with the datepickers and the loop, and your `UserTracking()` controller method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95324/discussion-between-paxsentry-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `Ajax.ActionLink()`, use jquery ajax method to update the DOM.

Change the  html to generate the links

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count(); i++)
{
  <a href="#" class="details" data-userid="@Model.Users[i].Id">Model.Users[i].Username</a>
}
```

Then include a script to handle the links `.click()` event, call the server and update the DOM. Note I'm assuming here that the additional values you want to pass to the controller method are the values of your 2 hidden inputs (`FromDate` and `UntilDate`)

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UserTracking")';
var placeholder = $('#userTracking');
$('.details').click(function() {
  var userid = $(this).data('userid');
  var from = $('#FromDate').val();
  var until = $('#UntilDate').val();
  placeholder.load(url, { userId: userid, from: from, until: until });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for. :) Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you using a datepicker and then converting its value to a 'long' and then passing that to the method, as opposed to attaching the datepicker to a textbox and passing the actual selected date?

Comment: Probably because of my inexperience, this the way I've solved it.

Comment: I suggest you consider changing that :) Your code is terribly hard to read and debug. And follow best practice and group all your scripts together (not inline)