# Passing TextBoxFor value to controller using @Ajax.ActionLink MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have gone through many questions with the "same" issue, but none seem to work for me(Or im completely missing the point).

As the subject says, I am trying to pass the value from a TextBoxFor to my controller using an Ajax.ActionLink, but nothing is working. I have tried javascript/jquery and tried using my model, all return null:

VIEW:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duplicatename, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtDupName", @placeholder = "Enter duplicate name" })

@foreach (var item in Model.MasterBudgets)
    {
                   @{
                        var optsImportsl = new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
                            UpdateTargetId = "listofBudgets",
                            //OnBegin = "ImportLoading"
                        };
                    }

                    @if (User.IsInRole("Super Admin"))
                    {
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("Duplicate", "Duplicate", "Budget", new { id = item.BudgetId, type = item.Type, dupName = @Model.Duplicatename }, optsImportsl, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-black btn-outline", @id = "btnCreate" })
                    }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Duplicate(int id, string type, string dupName)
    {
        var model = _masterRepository.FindMasterBudgetById(id);

        if(dupName == null || dupName.Trim() == "")
        {
            dupName = "Duplicated";
        }



if (type == "Master")
            {
                var duplicate = Duplication(model, dupName);
                var masterbudgetId = _masterRepository.Save(duplicate);
                var budgets = _masterRepository.GetMasterBudgets
                                    .Where(x => x.ParentMasterBudgetId == id && x.Type == "Budget")
                                    .ToList();
                //Budgets
                foreach (var item in budgets)
                {
                    var linkedAccounts = _budgetAccountRepository.GetBudgetAccounts
                    .Where(x => x.BudgetId == item.BudgetId)
                    .ToList();
                    var duplicateBudgets = Duplication(item, dupName);
                    duplicateBudgets.ParentMasterBudgetId = masterbudgetId;
                    var getId = _masterRepository.Save(duplicateBudgets);
                    foreach (var account in linkedAccounts)
                    {
                        var budgetaccount = new BudgetAccount
                        {
                            BudgetId = getId,
                            BudgetAccountId = 0,
                            AccountId = account.AccountId,
                        };
                        var newaccountId = _budgetAccountRepository.Save(budgetaccount);
                    }

                    var linkedBudgetEntries = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetLineEntries(item.BudgetId);

                    foreach(var lineEntryItem in linkedBudgetEntries)
                    {
                        var lineEntries = new Notes_Line_Entries
                        {
                            EntryLineId = lineEntryItem.EntryLineId,
                            fkiAccountId = lineEntryItem.fkiAccountId,
                            fkiNotesColumnId = lineEntryItem.fkiNotesColumnId,
                            Value = lineEntryItem.Value,
                            isNewEntry = lineEntryItem.isNewEntry,
                            budgetId = getId
                        };

                        _budgetEntryRepository.SaveDuplicateLineEntries(lineEntries,item.BudgetId);
                    }


                    var subbudgets = _masterRepository.GetMasterBudgets
                                    .Where(x => x.ParentBudgetId == item.BudgetId)
                                    .ToList();
                    //Sub-Budgets
                    foreach (var subItem in subbudgets)
                    {
                        var subBudgetLinkedAccounts = _budgetAccountRepository.GetBudgetAccounts
                        .Where(x => x.BudgetId == subItem.BudgetId)
                        .ToList();
                        var duplicateSubBudgets = Duplication(subItem, dupName);
                        duplicateSubBudgets.ParentMasterBudgetId = masterbudgetId;
                        duplicateSubBudgets.ParentBudgetId = getId;
                        duplicateSubBudgets.BudgetTypeName = subItem.BudgetTypeName;
                        duplicateSubBudgets.OrganisationId = subItem.OrganisationId;
                        var getSubBudgetId = _masterRepository.Save(duplicateSubBudgets);

                        foreach (var account in subBudgetLinkedAccounts)
                        {
                            var budgetaccount = new BudgetAccount
                            {
                                BudgetId = getSubBudgetId,
                                BudgetAccountId = 0,
                                AccountId = account.AccountId,
                            };
                            var newaccountId = _budgetAccountRepository.Save(budgetaccount);
                        }

                        var linkedSubBudgetEntries = _budgetEntryRepository.GetBudgetLineEntries(subItem.BudgetId);

                        foreach (var lineEntryItem in linkedSubBudgetEntries)
                        {
                            var lineEntries = new Notes_Line_Entries
                            {
                                EntryLineId = lineEntryItem.EntryLineId,
                                fkiAccountId = lineEntryItem.fkiAccountId,
                                fkiNotesColumnId = lineEntryItem.fkiNotesColumnId,
                                Value = lineEntryItem.Value,
                                isNewEntry = lineEntryItem.isNewEntry,
                                budgetId = getSubBudgetId
                            };

                            _budgetEntryRepository.SaveDuplicateLineEntries(lineEntries, subItem.BudgetId);
                        }

                    }
                }
                Success("Successfully duplicated " + model.BudgetName);
            }
return RedirectToAction("BudgetListInfo", new { searchTerm = String.Empty }); //This ActionResult being redirected to, returns a PartialView - This is done so that the items in the Table are returned in correct order(i.e. Parent, then children under the parent and children under the child items)
    }
```

Duplication Function:

```
private MasterBudget Duplication(MasterBudget model, string dupName)
        {
            return new MasterBudget
            {
                BudgetId = 0,
                BudgetName = model.BudgetName + " " + dupName,
                BudgetTracker = new Guid(),
                FinancialYear = model.FinancialYear,
                Description = model.Description,
                Status = model.Status,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                CurrentWorkerId = CurrentUser.Id,
                OrganisationId = model.OrganisationId,
                BudgetTypeName = model.BudgetTypeName,
                ParentMasterBudgetId = model.ParentMasterBudgetId,
                Type = model.Type,
                CurrentWorkFlowTypeId = model.CurrentWorkFlowTypeId,
                ParentBudgetId = model.ParentBudgetId
            };
        }
```

Ive read a lot of posts saying that things need to be done client side for the value to actually be passed, as using the model, will only work when doing a submit(server side) - But I dont know how to :( Im sure im just being stupid and missing a fundamental basic to get this to work.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: `@Ajax.ActionLink()` is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view (the value of the parameters are the original value of the model before its sent to the view). If you want to send back the value of the textbox, use a form and submit it

Comment: Do you mean I must use a FormCollection on the ActionResult that I am calling ? If so, Ive tried that, but the FormCollection returns no values. I unfortunately need to use the @Ajax.ActionLink to pass the values - So what way would I be able to do this?

Comment: Seems this is a similar case, but passing long numbers instead of strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753478/passing-the-value-of-an-id-with-ajax-actionlink. Basically using `$('#placeholder').load(url, {[passedarguments]})` with AJAX is more convenient.

Comment: No. I mean use `Ajax.BeginForm()` (not `Ajax.ActionLink()`) and mark it `FormMethod,Get` if you want a GET

Comment: But if you want multiple links with different values for the `BudgetId` and `Type` but just one textbox, then you need to use javascript to update the `href` attribute of the link (it which case, forget `Ajax` and use `$.ajax()` methods

Comment: Thanks Stephen, yes, I need multiple links with different values with 1 textbox(It is a table I am using from which the ActionLink is being clicked on) - Could you provide a sample of how I would use the $.ajax to do what I am looking for(Sorry, still newish at jQuery).

Comment: Can you show more of your controller method, and what it returns and what you want to do with the data it returns (and to notify a user - start the user name with `@`

Comment: @StephenMuecke My apologies. I have added in more detail for the ActionResult, as well as the one function that does the duplication. I trust this is enough to shed more light. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks for assisting me!

Comment: That makes no sense - you making an ajax call and ajax calls never redirect so `return RedirectToAction(...)` is pointless. What are you wanting do ultimately do? - update something on the exiting page (and of so what) or redirect?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I have taken over another developers work, so this is what he created - Ultimately what is happening is, a duplicate of an item in the table is being made, and then the redirect is to refresh all the data in the table(including the duplicated item/s). It seems he is doing the Ajax call and replacing the Div, with the updated data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145521/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-axlewack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Ajax.ActionLink()` is Razor code and is parsed on the server so that `new { ... dupName = @Model.Duplicatename }` set the value of `dupName` to the original value of the property `Duplicatename` before you sent the model to the browser. It does not magically change because of a textbox. You need to use javascript/jquery to respond to client-side events.

This will be easier if you use the `$.ajax()` method rather than `Ajax.ActionLink()`. Its unclear why you want to change the default `id` attribute, and I suggest the textbox be just

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duplicatename, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter duplicate name" })
```

then in your loop, create a link and add the items properties as `data` attributes

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MasterBudgets)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Super Admin"))
    {
        <a href="#" class="duplicate btn btn-sm btn-black btn-outline" data-id="@item.BudgetId" data-type="@item.Type">Duplicate</a>
    }
}
```

Note the additional class name (your previous implementation was also generating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes)

Then add the following script

```
var container = $('#listofBudgets');
var url = '@Url.Action("Duplicate", "Budget")';
var textbox = $('#Duplicatename');
// handle the click event of the links
$('.duplicate').click(function() {
    // get the values to be sent to the method
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var name = textbox.val();
    $.get(url, { id: id, type: type, dupName: name }, function(data) {
        container.html(data); // update the DOM
    });
});
```

As a side note, your method should be initializing the model and returning a partial view, rather than using `return RedirectToAction(....);`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above, but the controller isnt even being called. I checked in developer mode and the console shows this error : ReferenceError: $ is not defined. At this point I dont want to remove the redirect(I know you said this is silly and crazy), but I dont have much time to complete this project, and afraid that re-doing everything will take too long :(

Comment: What do you mean its not being called? Is this script in the view or a separate js file. What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: In the view. What I mean is the ActionResult is not being called(breakpoint not being hit). I edited my comment over with the error that I see in the console in developer mode

Comment: That means you have not included `jquery-{version}.js` in the view

Comment: But that makes no sense, because the `Ajax.ActionLink()` would never have worked. I can only assume you have included the script before `jquery` (your scripts should be immediately before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: Ah! I hear what you are saying! Considering this is the partialview(and I believe partial views are not supposed to have javascript etc. in them - sorry, I think I forgot to mention this part - doh!), I moved this script you provided to my view, from which this partialview is being called from. After this, my controller was called and worked like a charm! Thanks for your Patience with me Stephen!

Comment: Stephen, you will be glad to know that I have made the change to NOT use redirect any more :) I am now using a jsonresult, as you suggested, in addition to this, I am also using the Sweet Alert extension, so I now have a nice popup asking if this duplication should be done :) Thanks again for all your help!